# Does Mountain Lion support OpenCL 1.2?

Tags: opencl, osx-mountain-lion, osx-mavericks

I'm using Mavericks to write OpenCL code that should be compatible with 10.8 and 10.9 (Mavericks).

What versions of OpenCL are supported in Mountain Lion?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Mountain Lion is OpenCL 1.1 only.

Because NVidia still doesn't support 1.2 for political reasons you should write 1.1 code in anycase if you wish for your program to work on all macs.

Comment: But Apple do their own OpenCL implementation (http://forum.beyond3d.com/showthread.php?p=1793461) and OpenCL seems to be supported on Mavericks on all Macs. The first part is probably correct though.

Comment: Some NVIDIA devices show OpenCL 1.2 under Mavericks. However, older ATI and NVIDIA devices will still show OpenCL 1.1, especially on older OS versions. Unless you absolutely require 1.2 functionality, I'd recommend targeting 1.1